# Unity + Mobile browser controller. Thoughts?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, networking, mobile-development

I'm developing a game in Unity. I want it to be similar to Jackbox Games in the way that the main game is ran on a computer attached to a TV in a living room, but the interaction from those playing it come from using their phone's mobile browser to send their input. The difference that I want to accomplish is I want it to be semi-real time. Think Mario-Party mini game real time, where you might have to spam a button or do some light movement left, right, up, or down.

So here is the question: What is the best API for making the networking portion happen? I've looked into Unity Multiplayer, but it seems un-scaleable.  Websockets seems possible, and Photon looks enticing with the Unity integration. I'm looking to eventually publish this, so it can't be a short-term solution. Thoughts? I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go for Unity Multiplayer, There is nothing you can’t do using
   UNET. And it’s very easy to understand and implement.
2. Photon is the other option, Yes, so much scalable at some
   extent.It’s not that easy to implement but you will get through it.